# Ajax POST call Django's View with Multiple Data [Response 500]

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

This 500 status error is NOT CSRFtoken problem after integrating django-secretballot with my app called 'flavor'. FireBug Network tab shows

POST:

```
content_type    flavor.Flavor
object_id   5
vote    1
Source
content_type=flavor.Flavor&object_id=5&vote=1
```

Response:

```
TypeError at /flavor/vote/
vote() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'content_type', 'object_id', and 'vote'
```

**Could you spot any mistake in my flavor_vote.js below?? Why can't those 3 required positional arguments be passed into the vote() function??**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

  $.ajaxSetup({
      beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
              xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  });

  $(".vote").click(function () {
    var div = $(this);
    var obj_id = $(this).closest('.flavor').attr('flavor-id');
    var vote = 1;
    if ($(this).hasClass('voted')) {
        var vote = 0;
    }

   console.log(div);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/flavor/vote/',
        method: 'post',
        data: {
            'content_type': 'flavor.flavor',
            'object_id': obj_id,
            'vote': vote
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Successfully called');
            $(div).toggleClass('btn-success voted');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
  });
});

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
```

**========Other related information================**

My models.py has the Flavor class which is enabled to be voted

```
secretballot.enable_voting_on(Story)
```

My ajax call need to pass arguments to the `vote()` function in views.py at https://github.com/jamesturk/django-secretballot/blob/master/secretballot/views.py

```
def vote(request, content_type, object_id, vote, can_vote_test=None,
         redirect_url=None, template_name=None, template_loader=loader,
         extra_context=None, context_processors=None, mimetype=None):
```

urls.py has

```
url(r'^flavor/vote/$', 'secretballot.views.vote', name='flavor_vote'),
```

django template flavor_detail.html

```
<div class="caption flavor" flavor-id="{{ flavor.id }}">
    <div class="btn btn-default vote">
       <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></span>
       Vote
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: A 500 error means something went wrong server side - there must be a stack trace that can help you figure out what.

Answer (score 0):

Your `vote` function should only take one argument, the `request`:

```
def vote(request):
```

The variables you are passing to your view via AJAX will be present in the `request.POST` dict. They are not passed as `args` or `kwargs` to the view function.

```
def vote(request):
    content_type = request.POST['content_type']
    vote = request.POST['vote']
    object_id = request.POST['object_id']
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the valid answer. I accept another one because I donot want to touch the library.

Answer (score 0):

Two things need to change...

> First

Add support for positional arguments in urls.py

```
url(r'^flavor/vote/(?P<content_type>)/(?P<object_id>)/(?P<vote>)', 'secretballot.views.vote', name='flavor_vote'),
```

> Second

Change your ajax request like this.

```
type = "some type"; // fetch it somehow.
$.ajax({
        url: '/flavor/vote/'+type+'/'+obj_id+'/'+ vote,
        method: 'post',
        data: { //not needed now as the url contains it.
            'content_type': 'flavor.flavor',
            'object_id': obj_id,
            'vote': vote
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Successfully called');
            $(div).toggleClass('btn-success voted');
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Great. I like your idea. Only a minor issue, the 'content-type' shall be variable content_type [underscore] in URL. Also, it needs to be defined before using it. It works.

Comment: Oh , yes i just put up a dummy value, you can put that value from your js.

Comment: If I defined the can_vote_test() function, how shall this one be passed into the vote() in view.py by the AJAX call?

Comment: You want to define another method in your view.py , can_vote_test and you want your same ajax call to reach there ?

Comment: self-define a method can_vote_test() and then pass as a argument to vote() function through this same AJAX call?  can_vote_test is the fourth argument together with content_type, object_id, etc.

Comment: I have a way to hack it but want to know how can AJAX achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: You can add any number of arguments to your vote() , and for that you have to add those arguments in your url for it to reach your view function. Just like i have added the three arguments, you can add the fourth one there in the url of ajax block. Nothing special